alter session set CONTAINER with CX_Oracle
Now i use cx_oracle with python to execute oracle statements. I have oracle CDB and PDBs. I need to execute this statement from CDB to PDB (MYPDB)
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=MYPDB;
SELECT (SELECT instance_name FROM v$instance) as CDB_NAME, 
(SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CON_NAME') FROM dual) as PDB_NAME ,
a.owner ,a.table_name ,a.column_name ,b.comments 
FROM dba_tab_columns a 
LEFT JOIN dba_col_comments b 
ON a.owner = b.owner AND a.table_name = b.table_name AND a.column_name = b.column_name 
WHERE a.OWNER 
LIKE 'USR_%' 
ORDER BY a.owner, a.table_name, a.column_name ASC

It works in sql developer but not in cx_oracle. My script is:
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.user, password=self.password, dsn=self.connection_string)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""alter session set CONTAINER=PB24
                    SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, b.comments FROM dba_tables a LEFT JOIN dba_tab_comments b ON a.owner = b.owner AND a.table_name = b.table_name WHERE a.OWNER LIKE 'USR_%' ORDER BY a.owner, a.table_name ASC;
""")

and return ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Python version: 3.10.14
Oracle version: 18g
cx_version: 8 latest

That isn't a statement, it's two statements, so execute them separately. Is there a reason you can't just connecting to the PDB?

A side comment: don't forget to schedule your upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was released under the new name python-oracledb a couple of years ago, see the release announcement.

To give a concrete answer that explains the comments on the question:
Install python-oracledb:
$ python3 -m pip install oracledb --upgrade

Set the environment variables used in the script below, and then run it:
import getpass
import os

import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as  connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql1 = "ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=MYPDB"
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        sql2 = """select
                      (
                          select
                              instance_name
                          from
                              v$instance
                      ) as cdb_name,
                      (
                          select
                              sys_context('USERENV', 'CON_NAME')
                          from
                              dual
                      ) as pdb_name,
                      a.owner,
                      a.table_name,
                      a.column_name,
                      b.comments
                  from
                      dba_tab_columns  a
                      left join dba_col_comments b
                      on a.owner = b.owner
                      and a.table_name = b.table_name
                      and a.column_name = b.column_name
                  where
                      a.owner like 'USR_%'
                  order by
                      a.owner,
                      a.table_name,
                      a.column_name asc"""

        for r in cursor.execute(sql2):
            print(r)

